# Define a rule of derivative in NonCommutativeMultiply?

Tags: function-construction, rule

In tensor calculation, I need to do the following thing:

Define a derivative operator `Drv[fun,i]`, such that

```
Drv[f[i],j]=f[i,j]
Drv[f[i,j],k]=f[i,j,k]
Drv[f[i]**g[j],k]=f[i,k]**g[j]+f[i]**g[j,k]
```

---

**UPDATE**

I think this question in fact is quite important to me, and the answer, however is not quite complete, thus I will try to make the question more clearly.

The basic setting is that we want to define a *derivative* rule for the operator `NonCommutativeMultiply`, recall what's a derivative, call `Drv`:

1. To do the derivation, we must know who is/isn't a function with respect to  the derivative variable, since `Drv` acts on them differently. Thus as first step, it should be declare a set of functions that are real functions, let's say `f, g, h`.
2. The basic rule for a derivative is that:

   - Linearity: `Drv[c**f]=c**Drv[f]` and `Drv[f+g]=Drv[f]+Drv[g]`;
   - Distributive: `Drv[f**g]=Drv[f]**g+f**Drv[g]`;
3. for multivariable functions, we just write $Drv[f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n),x_k]$ as $f[k]$, and $Drv[Drv[f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n),x_i],x_j]$ as $f[i,j]$ and so on. For example:
   $$
       Drv[f,i]=f[i]\\
       Drv[f[i],j]=f[i,j]\\
       Drv[f[i,j],k]=f[i,j,k]
   $$
   the properties of derivative is just reads:

**linearity**
$$
  Drv[c**f,i]=c**Drv[f,i]=c**f[i], 
  Drv[f[i]+g,j]=f[i,j]+g[j]
$$
for c is a function which is independent on $x_i$. But when $c$ is a real number, 
$$
  Drv[2 f,i]=2f[i]
$$
**distributive**
$$
Drv[f**g[i]**h[j,k],l]=f[l]**g[i]**h[j,k]+f**g[i,l]**h[j,k]+f**g[i]**h[j,k,l].
$$

---

**UPDATE FOR 1st Answer**

1. could you just make some explanation for your code?
2. I want `drv[f[i,j],j]` output `f[i,j,j]` rather than `f[i,{j,2}]`. I think this is easy to do by `flatten`, but since I don't understand your code, I can't do it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build-in `D` do almost what you want with `NonConstants`. I just add converters from `f[i,j]` format to `D` format and vice versa.

```
$drvFunctions = {f, g, h};

fromD[expr_] := expr /. HoldPattern@D[f_[ind__] | f_, i_, _Rule] :> f[ind, i]
drv[expr_, i_] := fromD@D[expr, i, NonConstants -> $drvFunctions]
drv[expr_, ind__] := Fold[drv, expr, {ind}]

drv[f, i]
(* f[i] *)

drv[f[i], j]
(* f[i, j] *)

drv[f[i, j], k]
(* f[i, j, k] *)

drv[c ** f, i]
(* c ** f[i]   <--- with NCAlgebra package *)
(* 0 ** f + c ** f[i] *)

drv[2 ** f, i]
(* 2 f[i]   <--- with NCAlgebra package *)
(* 0 ** f + 2 ** f[i] *)

drv[f[i] + g, j]
(* f[i, j] + g[j] *)

drv[f ** g[i] ** h[j, k], l]
(* f ** g[i] ** h[j, k, l] + f ** g[i, l] ** h[j, k] + f[l] ** g[i] ** h[j, k] *)
```

I also recommend you to load the [NCAlgebra](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/) package. It helps a lot to work with noncommutative algebras.

Comment: @ybelltukov Thanks, I will just test it step by step, so there maybe some more problems will enconter.  I think, I just update my original question at the end?

Comment: By the way, say my this post is linked to my another question, (see the left sidebar: **Linked**), and there are the rules I need to simplify the expression, I believe it is enough, thus I don't try NCAlgebra.

Comment: @vanabel Now it returns `f[i,j,j]`. For better understanding please read the docs for `NonConstants` and pattern-matching and investigate the output of `toD`, `fromD`.

Comment: @vanabel Downloading the NCAlgebra is mush easy then implementing any non-commutative rules. It is a really useful and convenient package!

Comment: thanks, I will have a try! Your answer seems work for me, but can I take more examination before I approve it?

Comment: @vanabel Of course you can, nobody hurry here :) May be someone will find better solution. P.S. Does the order of derivatives matter? My method sort it alphabetically as in the regular derivative.

Comment: yes, it matters definitely!

Comment: @vanabel I just realized that it is even simpler! Please check my recent update.

Comment: I am sorry, I have give the bounty to the other one, it is a mistake as I have the wrong click. I will ask the supporter is there a way to correct it?

Comment: @vanabel Thank you for your generosity!

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

I did not fully understand your question at first. I have tried like this.

```
Unprotect[Plus, NonCommutativeMultiply];
NCM := NonCommutativeMultiply;
constQ[t_] := If[TrueQ[Head[t] == Symbol],
  MemberQ[Attributes[t], Constant], NumberQ[t]]

Drv[n_?constQ, i_] := 0
Drv[f_, i_] := f[i]
Drv[n_?constQ f_, i_] := n f[i]

Drv[f_[i__], j_] := f[i, j]
Drv[NCM[f__], k_] := Sum[MapAt[Drv[#, k] &, NCM[f], n],
   {n, Length[{f}]}] /.
  {NCM[a___, 0, b___] :> 0,
   NCM[a_?constQ , b_] :> a b,
   NCM[b_ , a_?constQ] :> a b}

Plus /: Drv[p_ + q_] := Drv[p] + Drv[q]
Plus /: Drv[p_ + q_, k_] := Drv[p, k] + Drv[q, k]
Protect[Plus, NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

This is your example.

```
Drv[2 ** f, i]
```

> `2 f[i]`

```
Drv[2 f, i]
```

> `2 f[i]`

```
Drv[f[i] + g, j]
```

> `f[i, j] + g[j]`

```
Drv[f ** g[i] ** h[j, k], l]
```

> `f ** g[i] ** h[j, k, l] + f ** g[i, l] ** h[j, k] + f[l] ** g[i] ** h[j, k]`

And these are additional examples.

```
Drv[c ** f, i]
```

> `c ** f[i] + c[i] ** f`

```
SetAttributes[c, Constant]
Drv[c ** f, i]
```

> `c f[i]`

```
Drv[2 ** f ** g[i], k]
```

> `2 f ** g[i, k] + 2 f[k] ** g[i]`

```
Drv[f ** g[i] ** c, l]
```

> `c f ** g[i, l] + c f[l] ** g[i]`

```
ClearAll[c]
Drv[c ** f, i]
```

> `c ** f[i] + c[i] ** f`

**Original**

Deleted

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make `Drv[f_[i_], j_] := f[i, j]` and `Drv[f_[i_, j_], k_] := f[i, j, k]` more general, such that `Drv[f_[i_, j_,k_], l_] := f[i, j, k,l]` and so on holds?

Comment: `Drv[f_[i__],j_]:=f[i,j]` works! But it seems that the basic rule of `Drv[f[i]**h[l]+g[j],k]=f[i,k]**h[l]+f[i]**h[l,k]+g[j,k]` is not holds, can you help me again?