# Simplifying a b = 1 in non-commutative products?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, rule

Yesterday, I try to define some rules for non-communicative multiplication, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61267/how-to-define-a-rule-of-derivative). I find some quite helpful rules, but things still do not work properly; the distributive rule can't be applied (e.g.: `-a**(b + c) = -a**b - a**c`), and the identity is not recongnized (e.g.: `1**a` should be equal to `a`). Then I try to solve all these problem by removing the attribute  `Orderless` from the built-in operator `Times`.

Any way, then I have some expression as (some term omitted):

```
ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless]
fab = a b + a b c + c a b + a^2 b^2 + a^3 b c + c a b^3
```

(It should be noted that `a b` is **not equal** to `b a` in my case).

I want to apply the relation `a b = 1` and `b a = 1` with the following rule:

```
rule ={a b -> 1, b a -> 1, a^i_ b^i_ -> 1 b^i_ a^i_ -> 1}
```

Sadly, It seems that the above rule doesn't work.

Comment: The notebbook available [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/) has a section covering various ways to work with noncommutative products, defining commutators, canonicalizing, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you really don't want to modify `Times`, as this will have all sorts of unforeseen side-effects. Your best route will be to use `**` ([`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html)), for which you'll have to write rules that enforce the behaviour you want.

Here's how you might go about that:

```
genericRules = {
  (* Move numeric factors outside of NonCommutativeMultiply. *)
  before___ ** (a_?NumericQ*x_) ** after___ :> a  before ** x ** after,
  before___ ** a_?NumericQ ** after___ :> a  before ** after,
  (* Distribute over Plus. *)
  before___ ** sum_Plus ** after___ :> (before ** # ** after & /@ sum),
  (* Remove singletons. *)
  NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] :> x
};

specificRules = {
  a ** b -> 1,
  b ** a -> 1
};

ApplyRules[expr_] := expr //. Join[specificRules, genericRules]
```

Then you can simplify expressions as follows:

```
fab = a ** b + a ** b ** c + c ** a ** b + a ** a ** b ** b
      + a ** a ** a ** b ** c + c ** a ** b ** b ** b;

fab // ApplyRules
```

> ```
> 2 + 2 c + a ** a ** c + c ** b ** b
> ```

Comment: what's the function of `NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] :> x`

Comment: @vanabel That's for the last step in this simplification sequence: `a ** b ** c` -> `1 ** c` -> `NonCommutativeMultiply[c]` -> `c`. This is similar to what happens for `Times`, compare namely the following: `Times[1, x]` -> `Times[x]` -> `x`.

Comment: @van By the way to automatically apply this set of rules to output you can set `$Post = ApplyRules`.

Comment: @TeakeNutma It seems that it is not: when I modify the code as:`genericRules = { NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] :> x };`, then `1**c//ApplyRules` output `1**c` rather than `c`.

Comment: @TeakeNutma May I invite you to take a look at my [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61267/how-to-define-a-rule-of-derivative)?

Comment: @vanabel I was referring to the *last* step in the simplification chain; your example needs the last *two* steps. So `1**c` is not simplified to `c` because your `genericRule` is missing the first two rules that move numeric factors outside of NCM.

Comment: @TeakeNutma So why `1**c/.before___ ** a_?NumericQ ** after___ :> a before ** after` output `NonCommutativeMultiply[c]`? I mean it is weird that here `before` shall be null, then why `before**h` return `NonCommutativeMultiply[h]` then?

Comment: @vanabel Sorry, I can't decode your last sentence. In any case, `___` is a [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html), which can match zero or more arguments. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsWithVariableNumbersOfArguments.html) for more information.