# Non commutative products and scalars

Tags: operators, products

Say I have an expression such as $$a.(\alpha b)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are non-commutative operators, but $\alpha$ is simply a scalar. How do I tell Mathematica to treat $\alpha$ as a scalar and "pull" it out of the non-commutative product? i.e. such that $$a.(\alpha b)=\alpha (a.b)$$
I've tried defining $\alpha$ as a real number, but this hasn't worked. I have to admit, I'm not particularly proficient at Mathematica and I'm still in the learning stage. Any help on this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're using `**`, I presume (as you did not show any code)? You'll have to teach *Mathematica* how to handle scalars, since `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` has no built-in rules.

Comment: @J.M.         So far I've just been using the $.$ product defined in Mathematica, since it essentially treats the product as non-commutative (due to the matrix multiplication). How does one teach Mathematica how to handle scalars?

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61306).

Comment: @J.M.           Ok, thanks. I think that should hopefully sort things out.

Comment: Also have a look at [the documentation for NonCommutativeMultiply](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) (under Applications). Definitely don't hesitate to add your code if there are still issues you feel need to be resolved.

Comment: @Jens          Ok, thank you. I haven't got very far with the code yet, but when I do, I'll post it if I'm experiencing any other problems.